# LINQ com condição em where usando variável

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
USUARIO

Nome      | Idade
João      | 21
Maria     | 18
```

Quero fazer em **apenas uma consulta** que retorne todos os usuários, ou que retorne somente os usuários com idade específica baseado em uma variável C#.

Também por nome.

```
int idade = 18;
string nome = "";

var resultado = (from u in db.Usuario
                 // Se idade != 0 considerar o where.
                 // Caso contrário, trazer todos os usuarios.
                 where u.Nome == nome && u.Idade == idade).ToList();
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Estou usando Entity Framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A não ser que a pergunta esteja mal explicada me parece não ser um problema com LINQ, é código normal:

```
int idade = 18;
string nome = "";

if (idade != 0) {
    var resultado = (from u in db.Usuario
            where u.Nome == nome && u.Idade == idade).ToList();
} else {
    var resultado = db.Usuario.ToList();
}
```

Note que está fazendo só uma consulta, ele não realiza duas. Se quiser insistir nisso:

```
var resultado = (from u in db.Usuario
        where idade == 0 || (u.Nome == nome && u.Idade == idade)).ToList()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/PartialWhere.cs).

Neste caso haverá custo de processamento extra na condição em cada elemento avaliado. Não é algo que vá fazer muita diferença em volumes pequenos, mas pode fazer em volumes grandes. Eu optaria pela outra forma. Sempre que possível é melhor tirar um processamento de um laço.

Comment: Perfeito! A primeira opção eu já havia pensado, mas é que minha consulta na realidade é bem maior e diferente na postada na pergunta. Realmente a segunda opção me ajudará a manter o código limpo. Faltou pensamento lógico de minha parte.

Comment: É uma questão de opinião, na minha o código limpo é o primeiro. Mesmo que tenha outras coisas para adicionar. Na verdade acho que com mais coisas, ficar mais importante fazer daquela forma.

Answer (score 2):

Simples lógica booleana

```
var users = from u in db.Usuario
            where idade == 0 || (u.Idade == idade && u.Nome == nome)
```

Comment: Perfeito! O que faltou realmente foi lógica de minha parte...
Apesar de ter sido o primeiro em responder, espero que não fique chateado por eu aceitar a resposta do @bigown pelas explicações...

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Claro que não :) Eu concordo com ele em que um if/else é mais adequado e facilita a leitura do código. Condições booleanas não-triviais escondem a intenção do código.

Answer (score 0):

Jedaias, se você tem uma condição dinamica ou complexa, talvez o melhor seja usar uma sintaxe de método ao invés da sintaxe de expressão.

digamos que você tenha dois filtros opcionais, no caso nome ou idade, poderia fazer assim:

```
var usuarios = db.Usuario;
if (idade != 0) 
{
    usuarios = usuarios.Where(usuario => usuario.Idade == idade);
}
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nome)) 
{
    usuarios = usuarios.Where(usuario => usuario.Nome.contains(nome));
}
var resultado = usuarios.ToList();
```