# Como usar a cláusula where com o linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Preciso fazer um join entre as tabelas pessoa e pessoaentidade de forma que o Entity Framework core traga Um registro correspondente. Vou ser mais claro:

Na tabela pessoaentidade, eu classifico meu cadastro de pessoas usando um enum. Fiz isso para guardar os Ids de cada cadastro (Pessoa, Cliente, fornecedor, etc). Se uma pessoa for um cliente ela terá uma ID, se ela for um Fornecedor terá outro ID e se não for nenhum dos dois, terá seu ID.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No momento, estou precisando dar um get no banco e trazer todas as pessoas que são físicas/jurídicas e que sejam do tipo PESSOA.Então preciso dar um join na tabela PessoaEntidade e fazer um where informando para trazer apenas do tipo 0 - PESSOA. Como faço isso usando o LINQ?

```
public IQueryable<Pessoa> GetJoinAll()
        {
            var pessoas = Db.Pessoa
                .Include("PessoaEntidade")
                .Include("Filial")
                .ToList();

            pessoas.ForEach(x =>
            {
                if (x.PessoaNatureza == PessoaNatureza.Fisica)
                {
                    Db.Entry(x)
                        .Reference(f => f.PessoaFisica)
                        .Load();
                }
                else
                {
                    Db.Entry(x)
                        .Reference(j => j.PessoaJuridica)
                        .Load();
                }

            });


            return pessoas.AsQueryable();
        }
```

Comment: após o ultimo include use o .Where(x => x.PessoaEntidade.PessoaTipo == 0).toList();

Comment: Relacionado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82752/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153264/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184843/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182176/101 e

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que ir percorrendo o o Objeto:

{

var pessoas = Db.Pessoa.GetAll().Where(a=> a.PessoaNatureza.PessoaTipo == 0).ToList();

}

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente ficaria assim:

```
    public IQueryable<Pessoa> GetJoinAll()
    {
        var pessoas = Db.Pessoa
            .Include("PessoaEntidade")
            .Include("Filial")
            .Where(p => p.PessoaEntidade.PessoaTipo == PessoaTipo.Pessoa)
            .ToList();

        pessoas.ForEach(x =>
        {
            if (x.PessoaNatureza == PessoaNatureza.Fisica)
            {
                Db.Entry(x)
                    .Reference(f => f.PessoaFisica)
                    .Load();
            }
            else
            {
                Db.Entry(x)
                    .Reference(j => j.PessoaJuridica)
                    .Load();
            }

        });


        return pessoas.AsQueryable();
    }
```